# How to create new image from a group of layers of the exact size as the biggest layer extends? (Cropping in photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, images

I am trying to crop an element in photoshop and I want to make sure it is perfect. I have a PSD that has many web elements that are grouped together nicely. I want to create a new image with the same size as the group of layers.

So basically I want to crop something out of the picture without losing or gaining pixels. I want an exact crop of the outer most item. Without using the crop tool and eyeballing it.

Usually I can use the rectangle tool and create a box around the item and go to edit>copy merged and then create a new image and it automatically has the merged layers size and then I paste.

My problem is for this group of layers is that it is not working properly and it is making the new image size the same size as the box and not the outermost layers.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: ermmm.... "I want to crop something out of the picture without losing or gaining pixels." makes no sense. The definition of crop is to remove pixels. Tried duplicating group to a new document then using Image > Trim > Transparent pixels?

Comment: What OP mean is that when you crop manually it's easy to cut something off on accident or have extra space remaining (that you didn't want) especially when dealing with "pixel perfect" cropping.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple method for this kind of work.

If your layers are aligned correctly in group, just convert this group to a smart object, open Smart Object and will have the pixel perfect margins.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tool you're looking for is the `Trim` tool. as Scott mentioned in his comment, you would go to `Image` >> `Trim` >> `Transparent Pixels`. This will give you an exact crop.

[This answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15291/auto-crop-layer-in-photoshop/15292#15292) may be of use to you as well.